# PHP to access to a .db file

Tags: php, database, sqlite

I am new to PHP and trying to create a search field that searches through my database file. I am putting my database file rc3.db inside the same folder that contains my PHP file and trying to connect it with mysqlite, however I

Tried  `$con = mysqli_connect("localhost:8888","user","password","rc3.db");` but errors,I don't have a user nor a password. Also tried `$con = mysqli_connect();` it works but I'm not sure if which database it is connecting to. I also did the single arguement with rc3.db as below, but it is probably mistaking that for the hostname, which is the the first parameter that the method takes in.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?> 
 <?php  
    //connection to the database
    $con = mysqli_connect("rc3.db");
    echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";
 ?>
 </body>
</html>


Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host 'rc3.db' (22) in    /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/searchform.php on line 9
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0005  229848  {main}( )   ../searchform.php:0
2   0.0005  230072  mysqli_connect ( )  ../searchform.php:9
```

Comment: It looks like you want `$con = sqlite_open('rc3.db', 0666, $error))` -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-open.php, instead of `$con = mysqli_connect("rc3.db");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your database is not a mysql db but a sqlLite database.
If that so, you can use the sample code bellow to access the data.

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:rc3.db');
$query = $db->prepare("Your sql query here");
$query->execute();
while($row = $query->fetchObject())
{
    //do your staff
}
```

**Update 1**
As @Sean pointed correctly in the comments as an alternative you can use [sqlite_open](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-open.php)

```
$con = sqlite_open('rc3.db', 0666, $error))
```

Answer (score -1):

The connection to the database using the extension mysqli.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
```

Answer (score -1):

use PDO like in code below. And read this https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/web/php/snippets/sqlite/index
It really helped me

```
<?php 
$db = new PDO("sqlite:tg.db"); // file tg.db in local folder
$db -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$query = $db -> query('SELECT * FROM tgdata'); // select all data from my table 'tgdata'
foreach ($query as $row) {
   var_dump($row);
}
```

Comment: how it's different from the accepted answer?

Comment: i use setAttribute(without dont work for me) and not use FetchObject. You can use just fetch but this give you only first data row (from Select for example)

Comment: Unfortunately, you are wrong on both accounts: 1. the setAttribute line, although highly recommended, but cannot make your code working by itself. It only helps to find the error, in case it happens. But for the working code, it doesn't change anything. 2. you should try the code before making such a claim.  `while($row = $query->fetch())` is as good as your `foreach ($query as $row)` and obviously will give you ALL rows. I find your answer rather confusing and misleading.

Comment: Ye, you are right. About fetch, just make bad explanation, i mean if using fetch out of loop.